# How to get error messages from NSIS to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nsis

I have a .NET application which runs NSIS files and execute them,
on windows XP I had a problem which is this window, that appears every time I run a file

using windows 7 made it easier, since if the .NET process was running as an admin that window will not be shown, but in XP it is a headache, 
I need a solution for only one of these problems,
If I can prevent this window from showing all the time?
Or I can read from NSIS exe file its output so the .NET will figure that there is a problem .

I have tried clicking cancel, it make .NET throw an exception, which is fine, I could handle, 
but not removing the mark on " protect my PC ... " causes the big problem.

this is the pic link:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5MtsIuVfrsYT2F1OGZUdHdMSDg

[image]

Comment: Why not let your .NET application prompts the users for administrator permission on Windows XP? Anyway the users should run your app as admin, on Windows XP and Windows 7, so your app should test and prompt, instead of waiting for Windows to do the same.

Comment: Are you using the runas verb?

Comment: @Anders that was the problem, thank you, I used Is user Admin function in windows api,, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with runas verb,
we can remove it, and in a replacement we should end the program if it is not running as admin
we can use this function to test if the app is running with admin permessions

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = True)]
return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)
static extern bool IsUserAnAdmin(void);
```

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.IsUserAnAdmin

regards,